# How to extend functions to Random class

Tags: c#, random, static, extension-methods, random-seed

I'm trying to extend the functions from a Random class.

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static void NextEven(this Random rnd, int min, int max)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static void ReseedRandomNumberGenerator(this Random rnd, int? seed = null)
    {
        rnd = seed.HasValue ? new Random(seed.Value) : new Random(); 
    }
}
```

But my doubt is the second function ReseedRandomNumberGenerator. I need something where many classes can interacts a Random class, but all those classes should have the same instance.

Suposse that I invoke ReseedRandom... it's possible than the others classes should refresh or updated the new seed?

```
public class A()
{
        protected Random Random = new Random();
}

public class B()
{
        protected Random Random = new Random();
}
```

I know that this don't work. Maybe I need a static property, I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you post code that illustrates desired behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the singleton pattern (See [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) on MSDN)

```
public class RandomSingleton
{
   private static Random instance;

   private RandomSingleton() {}

   public static Random Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Randon();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

You can then access the same instance of Random in your code anywhere as follows:

```
RandomSingleton.Instance.NextInt(24);
```

Please note that there is no need to re-seed this `Random` instance, because all your code will be using the same instance, hence you will not see repeated numbers.

Comment: Why not use a simple static Random instance(if thread safety is not the issue)?

Comment: Good point. You could. Although thus pattern gives lazy initialization - for what it is worth

Comment: Consider using 'private static Lazy<Random> instance;'

instead of 'private static Random instance;'
It'll be thread safe, and you don't need the 'if..' in the getter code, just ' return instance.Value'.

HTH..

Answer (score 5):

The `this` parameter is by-val, meaning: caller won't notice any reassignment you make to the value, hence your `Reseed...` method doesn't do anything that the caller will notice. To do that it sounds like you want a static instance somewhere, but then you need to watch out for things like thread safety too.

Personally, I would create a separate API, such as :

```
public static class MyRandom {
    static Random random = new Random();
    static readonly object sync = new object();
    public static void Seed(int seed) {
        lock(sync) { random = new Random(seed); }
    }
    public static int Next() {
        lock(sync) { return random.Next(); }
    }
    public static int Next(int max) {
        lock(sync) { return random.Next(max); }
    } 
    ...
}
```

The use of `lock` here prevents it all going unpredictable when being used by multiple threads; although at that point you can't guarantee a repeatable order *anyway*, but at least it won't explode in sparks.